# Change text string with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change/revert a text string when a link is clicked with Jquery. Now the first statement of this code works fine, but the the other one doesn't. Can someone please help figure out what's going wrong here?

```
<script>
  $("document").ready(function(e) {
    $("#newMessagelink").click(function(e) {
      $("#new-msg").toggle();
      if($("#newMessagelink").text("New Message") {
        $("#newMessagelink").text("Back to Inbox");
      } else if($("#newMessagelink").text("Back to Inbox")) {
        $("#newMessagelink").text("New Message");
      }                     
    })
  });
</script>
```

thanks!

Comment: What does $("#newMessagelink").text("New Message") supposed to do? If you want to check that #newMessagelink has text "New Message" you should use $("#newMessagelink").text() == "New Message"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) properly,

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
  $("#newMessagelink").click(function(e) {
    $("#new-msg").toggle();
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(txt == "New Message" ? "Back to Inbox" : "New Message");
  });
});
```

`.text("something")` will return a `jquery wrapper object`. If you pass it in a `if statement`, then it always evaluates to `true`. So fetch the text of the target element and check it properly.

Also you had some syntax errors like, not closing the opened parenthesis etc. Its better to see your console once before bringing your issues to other's attention.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9637r61y/)

Comment: So I tried your code, the idea behind using this code is to for a link to display "New Message" text by default. Once clicked, it should display "Back to Inbox". Then then when "Back to Inbox" is clicked, it reverts back to New Message.

Comment: @user3772369 Yes exactly. That is what you want. Right?

Comment: Yes, but with your code, when I implement it, it does not work on the first click for some reason. It works fine on the second click click and onwards.

Comment: @user3772369 Does not work in the sense? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, so when I run the application, by default, the text says "New Message" When I click on it, it hides a couple of things which I want, but does not change the text to "Back to Inbox". At this point, the text remains "New Message".  However, when I click again, it un-hides the divs that I want, and changes the text to "Back to Inbox".

Comment: @user3772369 The problem should be with the initial text. Check the initial text is having any leading or trailing spaces. Just use `var txt = $.trim($(this).text())` in our code instead of `var txt = $(this).text();`

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement will be always true since **[`text(string)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text)** returns jQuery object always. Instead you can do something simple using **[`text() with callback`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)**. Also you can use `this` instead of `#newMessagelink` selector, since inside the click handler `this` refers to `#newMessagelink`.

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
  $("#newMessagelink").click(function(e) {
    $("#new-msg").toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text == "Back to Inbox" ? "New Message" : "Back to Inbox";
    });
  })
});
```

with your own code change the if condition properly

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
    $("#newMessagelink").click(function(e) {
      $("#new-msg").toggle();
      var text= $(this).text();
      if(text=="New Message") {
        $(this).text("Back to Inbox");
      } else if(text=="Back to Inbox") {
        $(this).text("New Message");
      }                     
    })
});
```